# Custom route defined in asp.net core to simulate extension works locally but not in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an action  that returns a "mp3" file using FileResult, but I want to change the route to have the extension in the end of the route :

```
[HttpGet("{fileid}.mp3")]
public IActionResult GetFile(string fileid){

}
```

It works locally and returns the file. But when deployed to IIS, it throw 404 error.

Is there any configuration that I had to do ?

Comment: Do you have `ASP.NET Core` module for `IIS` installed and configured in `web.config`?

Comment: @Alexander , yes I have it installed and I publish it using VS tools, all other endpoint works except this one I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: `all other endpoint works except this one` I tried to create a simple sample to reproduce it, but it can reach to action and return a .mp3 file (both on local and IIS). If you can share a reproducible sample, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better. Besides, please check if any URL rewrite rule(s) cause the issue.

Comment: @FeiHan what kind of information could help ? Because at least on the appsettings. startup and web config I do not have anything to override the route.

Comment: To troubleshoot the issue, you can try to [enable Failed Request Tracing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/15/lab-4-install-and-configure-failed-request-tracing/) for your site, then check the log to find what exactly is happening with the requests and why.